# The number of intermediate field extensions $\mathbb{Q}(ζ_{630})/M/\mathbb{Q}$ of $[M:Q]=3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

I'm trying to solve this exercise: Find the number of intermediate field extensions $\mathbb{Q}(ζ_{630})/M/\mathbb{Q}$ 
 satisfying $[M:Q]=3$.

Since
\begin{gather} 
Gal(\mathbb{Q}(ζ_{630})/\mathbb{Q}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \times (\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \times (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \times (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \cong \\(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}) \cong G
\end{gather}
I think the number of such extensions corresponds to the number of  subgroups $H$ of $G$ of index $3$.
Any subgroup $H$ of index $3$ includes $3G$, so the solution is the number of subgroups of $G/3G \cong (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ of index $3$. I think those subgroups are generated by $(0,1), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2)$, so the solution is $4$. However, the book's solution is $8$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your solution is correct for me

Comment: @DietrichBurde
I think is a typo mistake; I think the OP means $Gal(\mathbb Q(\zeta_{630})/\mathbb Q) \cong (\mathbb Z / (630))^{*}$ and Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: Yes, exactly. So $G\cong U(630)\cong U(2)\times U(3^2)\times U(5)\times U(7)\cong C_6\times C_4\times C_6$. It is OK.

Comment: What about $(2,2),(2,0),(0,2)$ and $(2,1)$?

Comment: @ChrisCuster No; there are $8$ elements of order $3$ in $\mathbb Z/(3)\times \mathbb Z/(3)$, so there are $\frac{8}{\varphi(3)}=4$ (cyclic) subgroups or order $3$.

Comment: Oh yeah.  My mistake.

Comment: It should be $4$ as you stated.  However, when you said "$[M:Q]=3$", if you didn't mean $Q=\mathbb{Q}$, then it's possible the answer could be different.